# How do you redirect a standard stream of a C++ routine wrapped with SWIG and exposed to Python?

Tags: c++, python, swig, standards, outputstream

Is it possible to control the standard streams of C++ code in python? The code is wrapped with SWIG and then exposed to Python where I call one of its functions.

I am getting all kinds of unwanted messages coming from C++ code and I want to suppress them either by not using the output stream or by redirecting it to a bit bucket, e.g. devnull from the os module.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way is to implement a simple function/method in C or C++ of your extension to redirect the stdout output, see [dup](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/dup.html) for example, I think it will work fine.

Comment: Even if not redirecting this to STOUT, you maybe could send it to some PIPE or other FD which python could handle. As to iostream, I think you'll have problems w/ that.